# Enforce Light or Dark theme in Flutter WebView

Tags: flutter

I'm using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) to display a site. The problem is, the site is opening in dark mode. I tried setting MaterialApp theme and darkTheme properties to ThemeData.light(), but the webview is not respecting it and taking Device's default theme. Switching device theme reflects in the webview.

**How to enforce light/dark theme to the WebView widget explicitly?**

[image]

Here a main.dart snippet

```
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MyApp());
      
        class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {

            //please explain this one as well
            // SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
            //         statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark) // Or Brightness.dark
            //     );
            return MaterialApp(
              themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
              theme: ThemeData.light(),
              darkTheme: ThemeData.light(),
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              title: 'Flutter site',
              home: SafeArea(
                child: WebViewExample(),
              ),
            );
          }
        }
        
        class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
          @override
          WebViewExampleState createState() => WebViewExampleState();
        }
        
        class WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
          @override
          void initState() {
            super.initState();
            // Enable hybrid composition.
            if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
            // if (WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK)) {  }
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return WebView(
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev.',
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: have you found an answer?

Comment: @JohnJoe not yet...all I could find was that a webview(android webview or iOS's equivalent) is platform provided API and is independent of flutter's webview wrapper. So its control is at platform level, that's why android webview listens to system-level theme switches, even within a flutter app. 

Now, I don't want believe platform webview API doesn't offer control to override webview settings at an app-level. I feel dumb as I couldn't find answer since.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68109131/disable-dark-mode-in-web-view/70195085#70195085 I've put down an answer here regarding the same.

Answer (score 1):

Working on both mobile platforms, but note that it affects your whole app.

**Android:**

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68118246/7403507):

You need to modify `android/app/src/res/values/styles.xml` by adding this in your style:

`<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**iOS:**

Inspired by this [comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41067#issuecomment-571689955) on a related Github issue:

You need to add this in your `Info.plist`:

```xml
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```