# Disable dark mode in web view

Tags: flutter, dart, web, darkmode

I am developing an application in Flutter (with a webview) and when dark mode is activated on the device, the webview changes the colors of the web (text and background) to make it dark, creating a horrible result.

Is there a way to disable dark mode in web view?

I'm using this plugin [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding this line in `android/app/src/res/values/styles.xml`:

`<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>`

Here my full code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: how about IOS ?

Comment: It worked when it's added to both android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml and android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml . Thanks! You saved my day.

Comment: Sadly, doesn't work on Xiaomi Redmi with Mi Browser set as the webview renderer.

Answer (score 3):

this question being Viewed over 973 times, i couldn't stop the urge to post.

you cant do it form within flutter.
youll nedd to edit the native android code in webview plugin.

i used android studio find the webview plugin source code under:
External Libraries>Flutter Plugins>webview_flutter-2.0.13

you can use vs code too.

so  now you'll need to edit 2 files in the package

1. build.gradle under
   webview_flutter-2.0.13>android
   as such

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.2.0' //here update the version to 1.2.0
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.11.1'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.3.0'
}
```

save.

next is the webview_flutter-2.0.13/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/webviewflutter/WebViewBuilder.java file.

youll need to import few things or better replace

```
package io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import androidx.webkit.WebViewFeature;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.webkit.WebSettingsCompat;
```

in the same file you want to modify the 'build' method:

```
public WebView build() {
    WebView webView = WebViewFactory.create(context, usesHybridComposition, containerView);
    //this is the thing that we add
    if(WebViewFeature.isFeatureSupported(WebViewFeature.FORCE_DARK)) {
      WebSettingsCompat.setForceDark(webView.getSettings(), WebSettingsCompat.FORCE_DARK_OFF);
    }
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(enableDomStorage);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(supportMultipleWindows);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
    webView.setDownloadListener(downloadListener);
    return webView;
  }
```

and there you go my lazy fellows.

Answer (score 2):

So i am using InAppWebView and in my case after enabling the dark mode a black screen in coming till my data doesn't load on web view

to avoid black screen in dark mode i have disabled the dark mode of the app and enabled the "transparentBackground"

**==> To disable the "DarkMode"**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: AppLocalization.appTitle,
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      darkTheme: ThemeData.light(),
      initialRoute: AppRoutes.splashScreen,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routes: AppRoutes.getRoutes(),
    );
  }
}
```

**==> To enable the "transparentBackground"**

```
InAppWebView(
  initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(widget.initialUrlRequest)),
  initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
    crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
      transparentBackground: true,
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This actually worked, transparency is the key and would not work without setting it. I haven't tested it on iOS yet but android is fine. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Working on both mobile platforms, but note that it affects your whole app.

**Android:**

Based on [@John Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5156075/john-joe) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68118246/7403507):

You need to modify `android/app/src/res/values/styles.xml` by adding this in your style:

`<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             Flutter draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**iOS:**

Inspired by this [comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41067#issuecomment-571689955) on a related Github issue:

You need to add this in your `Info.plist`:

```xml
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the current theme by wrapping the desired widget in a `Theme` widget.
Something similar to:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Theme(
      child: InAppWebViewWidget(),
      data: new ThemeData.light()
    );
  }
```

Comment: ThemeData.light() ?

Comment: the content still change color

Answer (score -1):

I think the plugin doesn't have a parameter like 'ignore theme mode'. But, you can simply try the below method.

```
Theme(
                  data: ThemeData(
                    // Unique Theme Data
                  ),
                  child: InAppWebView(
                    //....
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: what should I put in ThemeData ?

Comment: Can you put ```brightness: Brightness.light```