# Flutter inappwebview not using system theme

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I'm using inappwebview to show my webpage in-app (currently using google to test), however it seems to not use my system theme. ie. when I toggle my emulator device from light to dark mode, google stays in light mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's an obvious thing that the Webview part will not use your theme as it has its separate from Flutter App.

We are just showing the webpage in Webview so indirectly it is not a part of our app.

**Even if you want to achieve this kind of thing, you can reload the URL when you change the theme in the app.**

#### Edited:

I think you can do something like this when you change the theme: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70195085/1318946

Comment: So there is no way to change the page theme whenever i switch the system theme from light to dark or vice versa? (besides reloading)

Comment: Yes, I don't think there is any way but I have edited my answer with one link. Might be that will change the dark mode of Webview not for particular website.