# How to change default dark theme of youtube when I display him on a flutter WebView?

Tags: flutter, webview

I display my youtube channel in a WebView but by default it's the dark theme. My app have no dark theme so i little ugly. I try to add `new ThemeData.light()` but no result.

```
new Theme(
    data: new ThemeData.light()
    child: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/XXXXXX/videos',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
             _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add themes to `MaterialApp`s and all the widgets as well before using it like this:

- Firstly you'll need to create a new class called AppTheme and add import

  ```
  'package:flutter/material.dart';

  class AppTheme {
     //
     AppTheme._();

     static final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData(
   scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.teal,
   appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
     color: Colors.teal,
     iconTheme: IconThemeData(
       color: Colors.white,
     ),
   ),
   colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
     primary: Colors.white,
     onPrimary: Colors.white,
     primaryVariant: Colors.white38,
     secondary: Colors.red,
   ),
   cardTheme: CardTheme(
     color: Colors.teal,
   ),
   iconTheme: IconThemeData(
     color: Colors.white54,
   ),
   textTheme: TextTheme(
     title: TextStyle(
       color: Colors.white,
       fontSize: 20.0,
     ),
     subtitle: TextStyle(
       color: Colors.white70,
       fontSize: 18.0,
     ),
   ),
     );

     static final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData(
   scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
   appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
     color: Colors.black,
     iconTheme: IconThemeData(
       color: Colors.white,
     ),
   ),
   colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
     primary: Colors.black,
     onPrimary: Colors.black,
     primaryVariant: Colors.black,
     secondary: Colors.red,
   ),
   cardTheme: CardTheme(
     color: Colors.black,
   ),
   iconTheme: IconThemeData(
     color: Colors.white54,
   ),
   textTheme: TextTheme(
     title: TextStyle(
       color: Colors.white,
       fontSize: 20.0,
     ),
     subtitle: TextStyle(
       color: Colors.white70,
       fontSize: 18.0,
     ),
   ),
  );
  }
  ```

Something like this.

- Secondly you'll be required to use these themes in all your widgets to be able to change the themes on a click of a button :

  ```
  return MaterialApp(
         title: 'Flutter Theming Tutorials',
         debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
         theme: AppTheme.lightTheme, // ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
         darkTheme:
             AppTheme.darkTheme, // ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
         home: ThemeDemo(),
         themeMode: appState.isDarkMode ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
       );
     },
   );
  ```
- Finally you'll want to use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) or something to
  save a bool value somewhere to be able to access light or dark mode:

  ```
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   prefs.setBool("theme", isDark);
  ```

Now you just need to check the "**theme**" value every time you open your application and voila you have implemented themes in your project.

Comment: Thank you, but It doesn't work, It change well my app theme (classic widgets), but not change the theme display by the WebView (my youtube channel). I don't know if I can interract with url to change the theme by default

Comment: Yeah  you have to update your website code to do that

Comment: Badly youtube is not mine ^^ user need to navigate deeply in configuration to find the light theme on youtube. My youtube account is well in light mode. But when I use the url on the webview it’s automaticaly in dark

Comment: You should check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68109131/disable-dark-mode-in-web-view/70195085#70195085

Comment: I see but only for android, It’s better than  nothing  but I don’t found  multiplateform solution.

Comment: Sadly you'll only find native solutions for this issue